# Drop down menu disappears when hovering over embedded video in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, embedded-video

I have a drop down menu with an embedded video. This video shows and plays fine in all browsers except IE.

As soon as you hover over the video in any version of IE the drop down menu disappears.

Current pulling a random video from a custom field added to posts within videos category using part of the following code.

```
<iframe title="Video" width="270" height="190" src="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recent_video' , true) . '" frameborder="0" name="wmode" value="transparent" allowfullscreen></iframe>'; ?>
```

It's under the 'categories' drop down menu - link to site: http://www.keyaspectscoaching.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this attribute:

wmode=opaque

instead of the name=wmode value="transparent

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input but this doesn't work and with this added to the code, the videos don't display at all.